# NoClassDefFoundError zeromq after installing on Mac

Tags: java, macos, zeromq

I'm having an issue installing zeromq on my mac osX Mavericks 10.9.2. I have successfully installed it on ubuntu, fedora and windows but I'm having trouble installing it on my mac(primary development machine).

First I think I tried a normal install but couldn't get all the dependencies easily and didn't understand how to complete the installation without using ldconfig.

so I opted for a brew install as described [here](http://brianoneill.blogspot.com/2012/11/compiling-storm-and-jzmq-on-mac-osx.html).

homebrew installed zeromq 4.04

then I cloned jzmq version 2.1.1 and ran autogen.sh, configure, make, and make install.

Since there is no ldconfig in mac, I added zmq.jar to the classpath and the libs in the java command when I tried to run an example. This is what I got.

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -cp /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar local_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 1 100
Error: Could not find or load main class local_lat
```

Trying to troubleshoot I took out the classpath option out

Added $CLASSPATH pointing to the jar file as suggested in the official installation guide and I get this.

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib local_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 1 100
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/zeromq/ZMQ
    at local_lat.main(local_lat.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zeromq.ZMQ
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

The main difference between this installation and the ones on the other systems is that I don't know how to point to and recache the libraries(ldconfig). But wouldn't the options/arguments for the java command take care of it. That's what the link I used suggested. Anyway, why could I be getting this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a colon or semi colon between /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar local_lat in the command line?

Comment: Just tried... didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and found out that this is because jzmq is not able to find the zeroMQ installation. There will be two jar files one generated by zmq installation residing in `/usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar` and other by the jzmq installation in the perf folder `/path/to/jzmq/src/main/perf/zmq-perf.java` so to test the installation use this command

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -cp /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar local_lat tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 1 100
```

Note that order of classpath is quite important here which is the reason of error. First the jar file generated by jzmq is to be referenced then the one generated by zmq.